# How to ensure everything but *.bin files get deleted from a sub folder?

Tags: python

I have the following code which deletes a sub directory named "debug",how do I ensure everything but '*.bin" gets deleted from the "debug" folder?

```
# look for any debug directories. we can remove them from the root
for directoryToCheck in directories_to_check:
    for root,sub,files in os.walk(os.path.join(outputdir,directoryToCheck)):
        logger.info('sub is %s'%sub)
        if 'debug' in sub:
            logger.debug('Removing %s' % os.path.join(root,'debug'))
            shutil.rmtree(os.path.join(root,'debug'))
```

Comment: There is a bug in your existing code if you encounter two directories that contain the word “debug” (but are not precisely “debug”) .. (due to the `'debug' in sub` check)

Comment: @donkopotamus -- it doesnt have to be exactly `debug`,as long as `debug`is in the folder name

Comment: You’ve misunderstood. You check if “debug” is in the name (eg in `"xxxdebugxxx"`) but then explicitly delete the folder `"debug"` (not `"xxxdebugxxx"`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly I think this is what you want:

```
import os
from re import search
from shutil import rmtree


def level(dir):
    return dir.count('/')

all_dirs = []
for root, dirs, files in os.walk("./debug"):
    for name in files:
        if not search('.+\.bin', name):
            os.remove(os.path.join(root, name))

    full_dirs =[os.path.join(root, dir) for dir in dirs]
    all_dirs = all_dirs + full_dirs


new_dirs = sorted(all_dirs, key=level, reverse=True)

for dir in new_dirs:
    if len(os.listdir(dir)) == 0:
        rmtree(dir)
```

First I go through all the subdirectories, delete files that are not `.bin` and collect folders in the `all_dirs` variable. After that i sort directories by depth and delete the if they are empty.